# FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables is deprecated

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to turn a Tensorflow Dataset into a NumPy array and I'm getting a deprecation warning:

> FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.

What is the "new" way of doing this?

Reproducible example with `numpy 1.18.1` and `tensorflow 2.1.0`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

ds = tf.data.Dataset.enumerate(tf.data.Dataset.range(20, 40))

np.vstack(ds)
```

What I tried: I can only do it with one dimension at a time.

```
np.fromiter(ds.map(lambda x, y: x), float)
```

Answer (score 3):

With just `numpy`, and using a generator expression:

```
In [105]: np.stack((np.ones(3) for _ in range(3)))                                      
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3254: 
FutureWarning: arrays to stack must be passed as a "sequence" type 
such as list or tuple. Support for non-sequence iterables such as generators 
is deprecated as of NumPy 1.16 and will raise an error in the future.:
Out[105]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

Using a list comprehension to create the arrays:

```
In [106]: np.stack([np.ones(3) for _ in range(3)])                                      
Out[106]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

I don't use `tf`, so can only guess as to what:

```
tf.data.Dataset.enumerate(tf.data.Dataset.range(20, 40))
```

produces. But as I understand it tensorflow has a distinction between tensors that 'generator-like', potential executions (pipeline?), and 'eager' evaluation, in which the tensors, and tensor expressions, are actually evaluated, producing arrays (or similar object).  `np.stack` tries to convert its inputs into arrays.

A code example for `Tf.data.Dataset.enumerate`:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])
dataset = dataset.enumerate(start=5)
for element in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
  print(element)
```

`enumerate` returns an interator.  You still have to iterate it, as in this `for` loop.  OR `list(dataset)`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#enumerate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tfds` to do so, you can check out the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/as_numpy).

Example how to use:

```
array = tfds.as_numpy(ds)
```